# python urllib2 request is prepending newline chars to post data

Tags: python, django, newline, urllib2, urllib

I have a simple python (2.7.5) script using urllib2 to post data to a django (1.6.2) app on a server. When the request arrives at the server, one of the posted values has been truncated and one of the field names has a CR/LF prefix added to it. This seems like an encoding issue but I don't know how to fix it.

The python script posts to the server like this:

```
auth = 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd))
header = {'Authorization': auth }

data = {
    'status': 'TEST',
    'activity_code': 'TEST',
    'sw_version': 'TEST',
    'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)

request = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
result = json.loads(response.read())
print 'result = ', str(result), '\n'
```

On the server, there's a django app that processes the request like this:

```
data = request.POST.copy()
error = {}

try:
    required = ['activity_code', 'timestamp', 'sw_version', 'status']
    for field in required:
        assert len(data.get(field)) > 0
except:
    error['message'] = 'required field is missing (' + field + ')'
    error['debug'] = data

if error:
    content = json.dumps(error, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/json')
```

Here's the output of the script after it receives a response from the server:

```
result = {u'debug': {u'timestamp': u'2014-04-16 14:22:15', u'\r\nstatus': u'TEST', u'activity_code': u'TEST', u'sw_version': u'TE'}, u'message': u'required field is missing (status)'}
```

Notice that the `status` field name somehow got prefixed with CR/LF and the `sw_version` value was truncated from 'TEST' to 'TE'.

Why is this happening??

Comment: Can you please show the lines where response is generated if `error` is `False`?

Comment: The sw_version is truncated by the same amount of bytes that are prepended (crlf), that is 2, so solving the first one will solve the second one. Just noticing

Comment: Can you print the contents of POST before making a copy?

Comment: Fixed by removing whitespace from end of auth header value, i.e. `auth = auth.rstrip()`

Comment: Good to hear. Just be aware that `encodestring` will introduce line breaks at every N characters. Probably better to use `b64encode` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not print the value of your `header` variable, but the problem you describe could occur if a `header` value ends with `\r\n`. Here's why:

A HTTP request header is expected to end with two \r\n (CRLFs), after which the POST data comes. The `urllib2` module will not validate header values to check if you have a CRLF in your value. If you do, the server thinks that the header ends one CRLF "too early". This will cause the POST data to start with the last CRLF of your actual header end marker. This, in turn will make the content-length header (counting the length of your original post data) to truncate the post data by two characters.

So I would recommend double-checking your headers.

Comment: You nailed it @Krumelur. I just added .rstrip() to the auth header value and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem uploading to pypi. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349391/why-does-pypi-upload-include-r-n-in-post-request-data Ant help would be appreciated